# Optimising and reducing redundant information when gathering game data

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, artificial-intelligence

I am developing an intelligent AI opponent for the card game Spit, and one necessary component is that it can identify every possible combination of usable cards that it can play consecutively. 
The AI has 5 piles from which cards may be played, and cards can be played in succession if their value is one greater or one less than the previous.

Cards that can be played consecutively are stored in a Relationship class, which is then stored in a vector. This would normally not be too much trouble, but in Spit, a player can stack cards with the same value on top of one another, meaning that those cards are also usable and must be considered as well.

The consequences of this are that if two consecutive cards are stacked (let's say 3 Jacks and 3 Queens), then the AI will create relationships for every possible combination of those cards, in addition to the cards remaining on the other 3 piles.

This can result in a VERY large number of possible relationships, and due to the large number of comparisons made using them it often causes the software to freeze until the calculations are made.

I know the code isn't particularly well implemented but I couldn't think of a way of using functions to clean it up. A limit in the possible number of relationships has been implemented as damage control, although it only works to an extent.

```
relations.clear();

// AI -- Card Analysis ~~ Identifies up to 8 cards in a relationship
for (int unsigned i = 0; i < usableCards.size(); i++) {

    for (int unsigned j = 0; j < usableCards.size(); j++) { // checks for a 2 card relationship
        if (usableCards[i].isRelated(usableCards[j].getIndex())
            and relations.size() < 80) {

            Relationship genRelation = Relationship();
            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[i]);
            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[j]);

            for (int unsigned k = 0; k < usableCards.size(); k++) { // checks for a 3 card relationship
                if (usableCards[j].isRelated(usableCards[k].getIndex())
                    and (k != i and k != j)
                    and relations.size() < 70) {

                    genRelation.resetCards();
                    genRelation.addCard(usableCards[i]);
                    genRelation.addCard(usableCards[j]);
                    genRelation.addCard(usableCards[k]);

                    for (int unsigned l = 0; l < usableCards.size(); l++) { // checks for a 4 card relationship
                        if (usableCards[k].isRelated(usableCards[l].getIndex())
                            and (l != i and l != j and l != k)
                            and relations.size() < 55
                            and aISkill != "Rookie"){

                            genRelation.resetCards();
                            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[i]);
                            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[j]);
                            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[k]);
                            genRelation.addCard(usableCards[l]);


                        }// end if k related to l
                        if (l + 1 == usableCards.size()
                            and (genRelation.getWeight() == 3)
                                || genRelation.getWeight() == 4) {
                            this->relations.push_back(genRelation);
                        }
                    }// end for l

                }// end if j related to k
                if (k + 1 == usableCards.size()
                    and genRelation.getWeight() == 2) {
                    this->relations.push_back(genRelation);
                }
            }// end for k

        }// end if i related to j
    }// end for j

}// end for i
```

So what I'm asking is, are there any better ways of doing this? Or is there an efficient way of checking whether a particular relationship already exists? (Checking whether the relationships themselves are identical by direct comparison would not work in this case, as the suits of the cards would differ)

Any responses are welcome, even if it's just to insult my code :)

[Edit] Code has been shortened to 4 card relationships to demonstrate how the relationships are stored.

Comment: sorry didn't read the code as it is to big and i am already after work. but can you use threads ? this could speed things up.
also you could try to think about some Data structure to hold the data and maybe do some optimization there.

Comment: This is actually in a thread, although it has to be joined to the main and therefore the rest of program will have to wait for it to finish. This also means that the AI's reaction would be delayed until the thread is finished processing, and by then it is very likely that the game scenario will have changed and information would need to be re-processed.

Comment: what i mean by thread, is lets say the first loop to extract to thread. and create usableCards.size() threads so that each thread will get as input the value i, and calculate with this value the rest of the function.
this could speed up the code. but create many threads.
but again i would try to see if some data structure can help first

Comment: Before I even attempt to address the stated problems, I'd want effective code.  Either demonstrate the problem with minimal code (two or three levels, not eight), or generalize the code you have.  Among other things, parameterize the loops that are currently nested, put them in an outer loop, and keep the individual indices in an array through which you can iterate.  Having eight unrelated variables and a separate loop for each severely lengthens your code and promotes copy errors.